# Clone a Class from one classloader into another classloader - ClassCastException

Tags: java, classloader

I know this question is being asked several times. but still I'm looking for a cleaner solution.
Lets says I've a Class A loaded by two class loaders (CL1 & CL2).. Now while processing, Class A loaded by CL1 is being passed to CL2. As Class A in CL1 and CL2 are two different types, I'm getting ClassCastException.

Is there a way to clone the Class A in CL2 (or make Class A from CL1 compatible with CL2)?

Comment: Unfortunately Class A is not serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution if the class is serializable, write it to a byte array using `ObjectOutputStream` then load it back at the other classloader using `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Looks XMLEncoder and XMLDecoder promising for this problem.. But seems the InputStream/OutputStream/Socket within the object are not converted to XML (i.e not serialized)?. The de-serialized object has these fields set to NULL.